# How to enable ssl on checkout process only instead of whole site

Tags: shopping-cart, ssl

i have configure ssl in my store but it is enable on whole site which have slightly slow down my site i want to enable https on confidential part of store like checkout process, login, register  and want other pages with http from different source my configuration is like this[image]

[image]

still it my checkout not work with https.kindly help thank

Comment: pls check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850287/where-we-define-checkout-page-has-to-be-https

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is standard Magento operation.

Just set a HTTPS URL as the secure URL, and enable "Use HTTPS on fronted"

Ensure you check the global/website/store settings as appropriate.