# Remove https:// from Category and product pages

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I want to keep https on my homepage, cart & checkout page, but not on category & product page. How can I remove SSL from those pages?

Comment: Did you have a look at this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/how-to-enable-ssl-on-checkout-process-only-instead-of-whole-site

Answer (score 0):

If your page is not suppose to be using SSL, or has unsecure elements, it is better to not use SSL on that page entirely.

A better fix is to remove the below tags from the module `config.xml`:

Your page will be forced to use SSL if admin is found in your `config.xml`. You can find it right below the the first end frontend tag, just uncomment the entire block and you should be fine.

```
<admin>

<routers>
<mymodule>
<use>admin</use>
<args>
<module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
<frontName>mymodule</frontName>
</args>
</mymodule>
</routers>

</admin>
```